# DependencyProperty default value and subclassed DataGrid breaks properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've come across some strange behaviour while trying to subclass wpf's DataGrid control.

Let's say I have:

```
class CustomDataGrid<T> : DataGrid { ... }
class FooDataGrid : CustomDataGrid<Foo> { }
```

And some xaml:

```
<local:FooDataGrid ItemsSource="..." SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" />
```

Everything works fine, and I can only select one row at a time. If I however attempt to change the defaults for SelectionMode/SelectionUnit by doing this:

```
static CustomDataGrid()
{
    DataGrid.SelectionModeProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( CustomDataGrid<T> ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( DataGridSelectionMode.Single ) );
    DataGrid.SelectionUnitProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( CustomDataGrid<T> ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow ) );
}
```

And change the xaml to:

```
<local:FooDataGrid ItemsSource="..." />
```

It does not seem to care about my defaults, and I can select multiple rows. Now, the weird thing is that if I try to set the properties manually in xaml again (while still having the defaults in the static constructor), I can still select multiple rows. So somehow overriding the metadata screws with the workings of those dependency properties, causing wpf to not care about the values set in the xaml.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual multiselect behavior is controlled by `CanSelectMultipleItems` property, which defaults to `true` and is only updated when `SelectionMode` property changes. Overriding default value won't call property changed handler, so `CanSelectMultipleItems` remains `true`. Now if you try to set values in XAML, dependency property system starts working against you: default value is `DataGridSelectionMode.Single`, and you are setting property to the same value, so property changed handler is not called again and nothing happens.

Simpliest solution - add a non-static constructor and initialize `CanSelectMultipleItems` property:

```
public CustomDataGrid()
{
    CanSelectMultipleItems = SelectionMode != DataGridSelectionMode.Single;
}
```

Also you could declare custom style for your datagrid and set property values in style - it seems like a more "WPF-way" to do such things.

Comment: Ah, that made perfect sense! And yeah I should probably have those defaults in a style instead, good point. Thanks a lot!